# How to parse JSON into an array (for google scripts)

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I am using Google Scripts, and currently have the following JSON formatted string that I am able to get from the API of a crypto site.

```
{"sellerCommission":0,"updateTime":1613134493127,"accountType":"SPOT","balances":[{"asset":"BTC","free":"0.00000000","locked":"0.00000000"},{"asset":"ETH","free":"0.05000000","locked":"0.00000000"},{"asset":"OXT","free":"1.00000000","locked":"0.00000000"},{"asset":"ZEN","free":"2.00000000","locked":"0.00000000"}],"permissions":["SPOT"]}
```

I would like to take this and convert this to an array. I'd like the array to be in the format of [asset, free, locked], and I would only like it to display in the array if the value of free is >0. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myfunction() {
  const jsn='{"sellerCommission":0,"updateTime":1613134493127,"accountType":"SPOT","balances":[{"asset":"BTC","free":"0.00000000","locked":"0.00000000"},{"asset":"ETH","free":"0.05000000","locked":"0.00000000"},{"asset":"OXT","free":"1.00000000","locked":"0.00000000"},{"asset":"ZEN","free":"2.00000000","locked":"0.00000000"}],"permissions":["SPOT"]}';
  const obj=JSON.parse(jsn);
  let oA=[];
  obj.balances.forEach((o,i)=>{
    if(o.free>0) {
      oA.push([o.asset,o.free,o.locked]);
    }
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(oA));
}

Execution log
9:49:40 PM  Notice  Execution started
9:49:41 PM  Info    [["ETH","0.05000000",null],["OXT","1.00000000",null],["ZEN","2.00000000",null]]
9:49:41 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great. A small type where you have "locket" instead of "locked" in the above example, but the concept is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Sorry about the typo.  You can expect that sort of thing as you get older.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Maybe a bit cleaner

const response = {
  "sellerCommission": 0,
  "updateTime": 1613134493127,
  "accountType": "SPOT",
  "balances": [{
    "asset": "BTC",
    "free": "0.00000000",
    "locked": "0.00000000"
  }, {
    "asset": "ETH",
    "free": "0.05000000",
    "locked": "0.00000000"
  }, {
    "asset": "OXT",
    "free": "1.00000000",
    "locked": "0.00000000"
  }, {
    "asset": "ZEN",
    "free": "2.00000000",
    "locked": "0.00000000"
  }],
  "permissions": ["SPOT"]
};


const mapToArray = arr => arr.filter(item => item.free > 0).map(item => [item.asset, item.free, item.locked]);

console.log(mapToArray(response.balances));
```